# Google Script not blanking off Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google Form which outputs its responses into a Google Sheet.

I have then set up the code behind this, so that it takes a Google Doc template, replaces the variables with the submitted answers and then outputs this into a pdf via email.

During this process, it copies the Google Doc template into a blank Google Doc which is what sends via email.

The code it uses is:

```
function emptyDocument() {
  var docID = '1z1wlQTKjQONjzkoFbNam2R-57vcJRCrt8rmMEAcmgb0';
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
  var body = baseDoc.getBody();
  while (body.getNumChildren() > 1) body.removeChild(body.getChild(0));
 }
emptyDocument();
```

When we receive the pdf, it displays at the top of the page, the last line from the previous document. Is there any way that I can get this to fully blank out the document without leaving any previous text in there?

Comment: Are you calling `saveAndClose` to flush any pending buffers before attempting to export to PDF? If not, you have unspecified content serialization status.

Comment: I can't find the reference but I'm thinking that you can't remove the last child.  There always has to be one.

Comment: Hi Guys sorry for late response, just found the email thread had gone to my junk inbox. Tehhowch im not calling saveAndClose no, and Cooper i have seen previous threads saying there has to be at least one line left in the document as you cant have "blank" documents sat there. I'm pretty sure this used to work for a time and then it suddenly stopped. Ive tried to remove the 1 to 0 after GetNumChildren but then i receive an error about leaving the document blank.

Comment: @tehhowch I am calling saveAndClose further down my code after i have defined my variable names, and told it what text to change in the template document. Once it has done this, it then references  saveAndClose